# Windows Live ID Continue Button Broken

Tags: authentication, federated-identity, windows-live-id

We have a production web application that uses Windows Live ID as its authentication mechanism. For several months now, it has been working great. However, in early August, we suddenly started experiencing a serious problem...

If the user is already signed into Windows Live (via our app in another window, or a different Windows Live app) and navigates to our site, a continue button appears. It says "You're already signed in", and lets the user click Continue and be redirected to our site. In early August, **this continue button stopped working**. You click it and it does nothing. We didn't change *anything* in our code, and lo and behold we're not the only ones experiencing this problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wliddev/thread/15405d0d-8c14-4e10-821b-55c3bae580bc

It's clearly a bug in Microsoft's page. What we need is a workaround - our customers quite literally can't get to our app if they are already signed into Windows Live. They have to go to a different website, **sign out and then go back to ours**. You can imagine that this is a pain, and makes us think twice about using Windows Live as an auth mechanism.

Pending Microsoft's bugfix, we are dead in the water and having to explain this to customers. We are looking for workarounds and working on our own.. our current solution is, 'Make sure you're not signed into Windows Live when you go to our web app.' Less than ideal. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by Microsoft.